# How to Properly Handle a Socket Client disconnecton in a Socket/Thread list?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, socketexception

I'm fairly new in trying to program with Sockets. I have a class whose instance variables include a client's socket and a client's thread, in the name called clientInfo. I created a list of clientInfos to keep track of the connections going into the server, where I've successfully managed to have multiple clients send messages to each other.

```
            listOfClients.Add(new clientInfo(listen.Accept()));
```

The thread of the clientInfo is in an infinite loop to always receive incoming data, as shown in the code below. The idea that I had was, if I get an exception from the server trying to receive data from a disconnected client, all I should do is remove the client in the list causing the exception, right?

I would iterate through the clients to find exactly at which spot in the list the error is coming from by sending a heartbeat message. Should sending fail, I now have the exact location of the problematic socket and then I would then close their socket, abort the thread, and remove the clientInfo from the list, right? I hope that I have the right idea for that logic. However, when I do so, I've still yet to truly solve the exception which is why (I think) the code shoots itself in the foot by closing all other connections as well. Honestly, I'm at a loss of what to do to solve this.

There's also the unfortunate factor of sending packets to each socket in the list, where the ObjectDisposedException is raised should I close, abort, and remove a socket from a list. Is there a way to completely remove an item from the list as if it were never added in the first place? I assumed removeAt(i) would have done so, but I'm wrong about that.

I've read many answers stating that the best way to handle clients disconnecting is to use socket.close() and list.removeAt(i). My desired goal is that, even if 98 out of 100 clients unexpectedly lose connection, I would like the remaining two clients to still be able to send each other packets through the server. Am I on the right path or is my approach completely wrong?

```
        byte[] buff;
        int readBytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                buff = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];

                readBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buff);
                //This line raises an exception should a client disconnect unexpectedly.


                if (readBytes > 0) {
                    Packet pack = new Packet(buff);
                    handleData(pack);
                }

            }
            catch(SocketException e) {
                Console.WriteLine("A client disconnected!");

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfClients.Count; i++) {
                    try {
                        string message = "This client is alive!";
                        Packet heartbeat = new Packet(Packet.PacketType.Send, "Server");
                        heartbeat.data.Add(message);

                        clientSocket.Send(heartbeat.toByte());
                    }
                    catch (SocketException ex) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Removing " + listOfClients[i].clientEndPointy.Address + ":" + listOfClients[i].clientEndPointy.Port);

                        //listOfClients[i].clientSocket.Disconnect(reuseSocket: true);
                        listOfClients[i].clientSocket.Close();
                        listOfClients[i].clientThread.Abort();
                        listOfClients.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is only for questions pertaining to the Visual Studio IDE, not for problems with code merely written in the Visual Studio environment.

Comment: Side note: your code is also broken for another reason. `readBytes` tells you *how many bytes of `buff` contain actual received data rather than still being empty*. But you only pass `buff` to your `Packet` constructor so you're losing information. There is **no** guarantee that each call to `Receive` is going to populate your buffer with exactly one, entire, "packet".

Comment: Thanks john! I'll keep that in mind. Also, thank you as well, Damien! That's a fatal typo I'll correct that I didn't see before.